# Can't call non static method

Tags: java, methods, static

I am trying to use this `wavRead(filename)` but am getting the message `cannot make a static reference to a non static method`.

I could simply make it static and that solves my problem, but how would do it without going that route. I would like to keep the method non static.

Here is a bit of the code to let you see whats going on:

```
public class Sound {

double [] mySamples;
public static void main(String[] args){

    String filename = null;
    System.out.println("Type the filename you wish to act upon.");
    Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    filename = scanIn.next();
    wavRead(filename);


}
public void  wavRead(java.lang.String fileName){
    mySamples = WavIO.read(fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create an instance of your class

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String filename = null;
    System.out.println("Type the filename you wish to act upon.");
    Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    filename = scanIn.next();
    Sound sound = new Sound();
    sound.wavRead(fileName);
}
```

It's an instance method, it requires an instance to access it. Please go through the [official tutorials on classes and objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot call non-static methods or access non-static fields from `main` or any other static method, because non-static members belong to a class *instance*, not to the entire class.

You need to make an instance of your class, and call `wavRead` on it, or make `wavRead` and `mySamples` static:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sound instance = new Sound();
    ...
    instance.wavRead(fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a `Sound` object before you can call `wavRead` on it.  Something like

```
Sound mySound = new Sound();
mySound.wavRead(filename);
```

Static just means that you don't need to have an instance of the class that the method belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to call a non-static method from a static method is to have an instance of the class.

Comment: The only way to call a non-static method ANYWHERE is to have an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

static method can call directly to the another static method in the same class.you dont need to create object of class.
if call the non static method then first create the object of the class and call the object.non static method.