# Why do methods on arrays have to be static (Java)?

Tags: java, static

I don't understand why methods on arrays, in Java, have to be static. Static methods can only be used on static variables right? So this would mean arrays are static variables, variables shared by a class? But what class would this be?

Can someone help me understand this?

Edit: to be more specific, I am creating methods to act on arrays but if I just write "public int[] expandArr(int[]a, int v)" and I try to use this method in the main method, I get an error saying I can't make a static reference to a non-static method. When I write "public static int[] expandArr(int[]a, int v)" it works then.

I understand you cannot change the size of an array, the method I wrote makes a new array with increased size and copies the first one into it.

Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think this? Arrays can be instance objects like anything else.

Comment: I think the provider of this information, whoever it was, meant that arrays are static in size. This means that an array instantiated with size 10 can never become size 11, it does not mean arrays are only accessible by static methods.

Comment: If thats the case, the part about static methods only using static variables doesnt make sense. If thats what they actually mean, an array cant have its size changed because they are contiguous in memory, and there is no guarantee that the required adjacent memory space will be free for the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you tried to write this:

```
public int[] expandArr(int[]a, int v)
```

The thing is, you had to write it in *some* class, since you can't just have free-floating methods in your program.  Therefore, it must operate on a instance of the class.  For example:

```
public class MyProgram {

    public int[] expandArr(int[]a, int v) { ... }

    public static void main(String[] args) { ... }

}
```

`expandArr` requires an instance of `MyProgram`, since you didn't declare it to be `static`.  And that has nothing to do with arrays.  It would be the same if you wrote

```
public class MyProgram {

    public String expandString(String s, int v) { ... }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
         String s = expandString(args[0], 1);  // ILLEGAL
         String s2 = args[0].expandString(1);  // ILLEGAL
    }
}
```

Although the first parameter of `expandString` is a `String`, this actually operates on a `MyProgram`, and you cannot use `expandString` without an instance of `MyProgram` to operate on.  Making it `static` means that you can (the first use of `expandString` in my example would become legal.)

In general, you can't add methods to a class without modifying the source of that class.  If you want to write a new method that does something with objects of a certain class `C`, and you can't modify class `C` (perhaps because it's in the Java library or someone else's library), then you'll need to put the method in some other class `C2`, and most of the time you will need to make the method `static` since it doesn't involve objects of class `C2`.

Comment: Thank you that was very clear. If my teacher told our class "static methods can only be used on static variables", doesnt this go against what youre saying though? If I create a method in MyProgram and make it static, then I cannot use it on MyProgram instance variables as they are not static? By static variables did he just mean any primitive type variables used in the main method do you think?

Comment: "If I create a method in MyProgram and make it static, then I cannot use it on MyProgram instance variables as they are not static?"  Correct.  If you want to use `MyProgram` instance variables, you need a `MyProgram` instance, and a `static` method by definition wouldn't have a `MyProgram` instance.  It has nothing to do with whether the types are primitive or arrays or whatever.

Comment: P.S. To clarify this, a `static` method can't *directly* access instance variables in the class, since there's no instance.  But it can access anything that's accessible using the method's arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a non-static method from a static method unless you first instantiate the an object of the class.

e.g.

In class Whatever...

```
public boolean ok() {
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Whatever w = new Whatever();
    System.out.println(w.ok());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant call a non static method from a static context. A static method belongs to the class, non static or instance methods are copied to each instance of the class (they each have their own). If I have 10 instances of class A, and class A has a static method, which all of them share, then I try to invoke a non static method in class A from class A's static method, which instance of class A gets its method invoked? The behavior is undefined.

The question really has nothing to do with arrays.

This question is related: [Can't call non static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149504/cant-call-non-static-method)

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand. So does this mean that if I wanted to keep it non-static, if I use it in the main method I would need to do d.expandArr(...) for some array d? And is what you're saying implying that arrays are a class? Sorry this is still a bit confusing to me..In class my teacher told us that static methods can only be used on static variables, I think this is where Im getting mixed up.

Comment: You would need to make an instance of the class inside of your static method, then invoke the non static method via its reference. like this:  MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();  myInstance.myInstanceMethod(myArray); See Bills answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're referring to is the fact that you can't extend an array class and hence can't add a method to it:

```
// No way to do this
int[] array;
array.myMethod();
```

This means your only option is to make a static helper method somewhere:

```
// So you have to do this
int[] array;
Utils.myMethod(array);

class Utils {
    static void myMethod(int[] array) {
        ...
    }
}
```

An example of this is the [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class, which has lots of static methods for operating on arrays. Conceptually it would be clearer if these methods could be added to the array classes, but you can't do that in Java (you can in other languages like Javascript).

Answer (score 0):

That is why we use other classes like the ArrayList to make them grow dynamically in size. At the core of an arraylist you will simply find an array that is renewed in size whenever the class figures out it necessary. If I'm understanding your question right.