# .add() returns a boolean in Java, how to return as a list

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I've been reading about this for a while now and I can't figure it out. Consider these classes, both in their own file.

```
public class World {
    private List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Entity> getEntities() {
        return entities;
    }

    public void setEntities(List<Entity> entities) {
        this.entities = entities;
    }
}

public Class Entity { 
    public Entity() {
        List<Entity> modifiedList = World.getEntities().add(this); // 1
        World.setEntities(modifiedList);
    }
}
```

There's a type mismatch: I cannot convert from boolean to List (1) How would I solve this? How could you possibly convert a boolean to a List? Also, the concept static confuses me. If anyone can direct me to some light, and accessible read about static vs non-static, please post it in the comments!

Comment: Why don't you just store the result of `getEntities` in the variable `modifiedList`, then invoke `add` on `modifiedList`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Isn't that just moving the problem from line 1 to line 2?

Comment: See the javadoc for `boolean Collection#add(T)`

Comment: Using `World.<method>` is attempting to call a static <method> on World.  Your World methods are not static, and instead pertain to each world object.  You need to pass in a World object in the Entity constructor `public Entity(World w)` and use `w.getEntities()` instead of `World.getEntities()`

Comment: Also, you need to realize that calling `World.setEntities()` is useless. All you need here is `World.getEntities().add(this);`

Comment: @BramVanroy No. You wouldn't reassign the result of `add` to anything. Or what JB just said.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis So if I get it right, by using .add you can use a getter method as a setter method? Because the initial value of entities is private, and you only *get* its value with a getter, but then you can modify its contents by using add? But how then is the new list returned?

Comment: `getEntities` returns a value. That value is a reference to a `List` object. You can use it to invoke methods of that `List`.

Comment: If you think so, please clean up your question to be specific about which issue you're asking about.

Comment: Forgetting, for the moment, the static issue ... as it is implemented,  there is only one `List` in your code above. There is no need to return a "new" `List`, because there is no new `List`. The call to `getEntities()` returns the actual `List` that is in your `World`. It does not make a copy in any way. Adding items to this list adds them to this same `List`, the one that is in the `World`. Ergo, there is no need to return a new `List`, as you are modifying the only `List` in your program.

Comment: @dcsohl I was confused with the power of lists. I thought you'd only be able to change the contents of a list throught a getter method, embedded in a setter method, because you'd nee the setter to set the list to the old list + new item. Apparently that's not necessary in lists!

Comment: That's not a feature of Lists, it's how java's references to objects (such as Lists) work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared a class

```
public class World {
    private List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Entity> getEntities() {
        return entities;
    }

    public void setEntities(List<Entity> entities) {
        this.entities = entities;
    }
}
```

which declares two [**instance** methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), `getEntities` and `setEntities`. These are **instance** methods, so you need an instance to invoke them. [That's what that duplicate was saying.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149504/cant-call-non-static-method)

```
World world = new World();
```

`World#getEntities` has a return type of `List`. `List` has an [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) method with a return type of `boolean`, where the value of the `boolean` typically indicates whether the value was added or not. If you don't need that information, ignore the returned value

```
List<Entity> entities = world.getEntities();
entities.add(this);
```

`getEntities` returns a reference to the same object referenced by the field `entities` in the object referenced by `world` in my example above. There's no point invoking `setEntities` to re-assign it.

Further reading:

- [What is the difference between a variable, object, and reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010172/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-object-and-reference)
- [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)